# Systems Table that records all changes to database

Tags: database, oracle

I am using oracle database for a web application.

Is there a table inside system database that records any or all changes that occur inside the database?

For example, if I insert a row or update a row, it would record this change inside a table.

Does this kind of table exist inside oracle database?

In mysql there is INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES that records everything that occurs inside the database.

Comment: why do you need this? What mysql table are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle too provides auditing mechanisms for your DB however, the subject is very extensive to be treated in a simple answer, since control can go down to a very fine grained auditing. Take a look at [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50000) on this theme, good luck.